# ¿Existe el tiempo pasado continuo en el idioma español?

Tags: categorías-gramaticales

Mi duda es si el tiempo verbal Pasado continuo existe en el idioma español.

Comment: Yo estaba cenando cuando tocaron en la puerta.  ¿Así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En español, **no** existe un tiempo verbal "pasado continuo" como existe en inglés. Lo que existe es una **perífrasis verbal** compuesta por el verbo *estar* en pretérito imperfecto (*estaba*, etc.) o pretérito perfecto simple (*estuve*, etc.) y el gerundio del verbo indicativo de la acción:

- Estaba comiendo cuando él llegó.
- Estuve comiendo hasta que él llegó.

A diferencia del inglés, en español contamos con el pretérito imperfecto del indicativo para referirnos a acciones durativas en contraposición a acciones puntuales expresadas a través del pretérito perfecto simple:

- **Comía** cuando él llegó (*I was eating when he arrived*).

Answer (score 2):

Sí, se forma con el verbo *estar* conjugado en pretérito imperfecto o pretérito perfecto simple + el gerundio del verbo correspondiente. El primero se utiliza normalmente cuando ocurre una cosa en el pasado mientras está sucediendo otra. Por ejemplo:

> (Yo) **estaba cocinando**, cuando (tú) llamaste al timbre.

El segundo se utiliza para hablar de acciones finalizadas realizadas en el pasado. Por ejemplo:

> Ayer **estuve visitando** París.

Aunque en este último caso, personalmente, me sonarían bien ambos, prefiero el uso del pretérito perfecto simple, en el primer caso si no utilizases el imperfecto sonaría raro/incorrecto.

Puedes encontrar más información al respecto en:

- [Madrid Teacher](https://www.madridteacher.com/Grammar/pasado-continuo.htm)
- [Blog de español para extranjeros](http://espanol1languageplanettoluca.blogspot.com/p/pasado-continuo.html)

Y tienes una discusión en WordReference acerca de la diferencia en el uso de estaba/estuve en el caso de pasado continuo:

- [WordReference - Pasado Continuo Estaba o Estuve](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/estuve-estaba-gerundio.738846/)